# How to remove the grey border in network manager applet

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, networkmanager

I'm using nm-applet in xfce, however it displays a grey border like the following:

[image: screenshot of nm-applet in xfce]

I tried to debug the panel by doing:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
xfce4-panel -q                                                           
GTK_DEBUG=interactive xfce4-panel
```

But I cannot find the nm-applet, using the inspector and clicking it the nm-applet doesn't show up. I can only find the `pulseaudio` plugin.

Any ideas on how to find it or remove the grey border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few months, my other solution no longer works. This made me quite frustrated, and didn't have any luck with the GTK inspector.

But today I discovered you can simply right click the "Notification Area" and uncheck "Show frame". There's actually an option for this now!

The relevant update to `.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml` is as follows:

```
<property name="plugin-6" type="string" value="systray">
  <property name="names-visible" type="array">
    ...
  </property>
  <property name="names-ordered" type="array">
    <value type="string" value="vlc"/>
    <value type="string" value="nemo"/>
    <value type="string" value="networkmanager applet"/>
  </property>
  <property name="show-frame" type="bool" value="false"/>
</property>
```

Comment: have you tried other themes and other panel settings, especially its appearance?

Comment: @cipricus Nah not really, the default theme's nice enough. Where would I find some extra themes?

Comment: As the panel is set to transparent, it looks like so: https://paste.pics/6LRSK

Comment: https://www.xfce-look.org/ . I like Vertex dark, for that [this](https://erikdubois.be/how-to-completely-install-all-aspects-of-the-vertex-dark-theme-on-linux-mint-17-3/) post was useful. But the answer to your question was indeed simple: unchecking "show frame", as you said.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, ToZ at https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11551 posted the following answer, and says it happens when we use the Adwaita theme in GTK2:

```
style "transparent-frame" {
  engine "pixmap" {
    image {
      function = SHADOW
      file     = "gfx/icons/transparent.png"
      border   = {0, 0, 0, 0}
      stretch  = TRUE
    }

    image {
      function       = SHADOW_GAP
      file           = "gfx/icons/transparent.png"
      border         = {0, 0, 0, 0}
      stretch        = TRUE
      gap_start_file = "gfx/icons/transparent.png"
      gap_end_file   = "gfx/icons/transparent.png"
    }
  }
}
widget_class "*Xfce*" style "transparent-frame"
```

I'm not quite sure how to find a more specific `widget_class`, but the above works.